# Does this get optimized out?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

My assert macro is like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define ASSERT(x) ((void)(!(x) && assert_handler(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__) && (exit(-1), 1)))
#else 
#define ASSERT(x) ((void)sizeof(x))
```

I thought this was more or less bulletproof but I seem to be using it a lot in the context of asserting the return value of functions which are important for their side effects. If in my release build I end up compiling

```
ASSERT(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),file));
```

which would become

```
((void)sizeof(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),file)));
```

Is there a chance this will get completely optimized out? I am fairly certain that it won't (I'm calling a function, `fgets`), but what exactly is the condition that assures it? Are there any operations with side effects which the optimizer might throw out?

Comment: Usually, you write assertions so that they don't have any side effect and hence can be remoevd. Do the `fgets` on its own line, save the result, then use `assert(result != NULL)`. Then define the non-debug `assert` to discard `x`. Or while we're at it, isn't there an `assert` in the stdlib?

Comment: Okay, so asserts simply aren't meant to be used with side effects. I feel silly now. Having my own assert is nice because it traces very easily in a debugger as opposed to popping up from some CRT, and I can control its behavior (app-specific alert? stderr? passive? abort program?)

Comment: The purported "assert with side effects" is sometimes called "verify", so you could name your macro like that. "assert" is commonly understood to not be required as part of your program logic.

Comment: I was trying to come up with a good word to describe it and "verify" fits the bill. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual meaning of assert is to be optimized out, so it might be better to stick to those semantics and do

```
#else 
#define ASSERT(x)
#endif
```

If you insist on it not being optimized out, why not just do

```
#else 
#define ASSERT(x) ((void)(x))
#endif
```

?

Comment: why don't simply `#define ASSERT(x) x` ?

Comment: @yi_H: Sure.  I guess this way, you are explicitly discarding the return value, so no one can write `if (ASSERT(x))…`

Comment: Many of the ideas came from this: http://cnicholson.net/2009/02/stupid-c-tricks-adventures-in-assert/ It seems like I need to reassess how I use these macros. Maybe I should be using different versions of asserts.

Comment: @yi_H: That definition will generate compiler warnings.

Comment: To be more specific, the exact reason for the `sizeof` is so that it suppresses "variable declared but not referenced" type warnings. The canonical `int r=func(); assert(r==OK)` when using `#define assert(x) ` for optimizing it out would leave r hanging. I use the `sizeof` trick as an unused macro: `#define UNUSED(x) ((void)sizeof(x))` so ASSERT becomes UNUSED (no instructions generated, no warning) when compiling for release

Comment: @Steven: why not put `func()` into your assert then so that it's not called at all in release?

Comment: @Neil G, Because a function can have side effects in general. Now, since i've fixed my macros, I would use `VERIFY(OK==func());`

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with optimization.  When you evaluate a `sizeof` expression, the operand never gets evaluated.  For example,

```
char func(void) { exit(1); }

size_t sz = sizeof(func());
// same as
size_t sz = 1;
```

If you want to retain the side effects without generating compiler warnings, you can cast to `void` as Neil G noted in his answer.

Comment: Sizeof is not necessarily evaluated at compile time.  For example, `size_t func(int x) { int a[x]; return sizeof(a); }`.